# Add current date and time to specific user in table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add the current date and time to a specific row within the database. I'm working on a project that stores the date and time of when the user last logged online.

I've currently got

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "UPDATE Login SET Last Logged='$date' WHERE Email='$email'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

It current stores `0000-00-00`.

Is this along the right lines? or have I gone on off the beaten track?

I've look for other questions asked, but couldn't see any that may answer this.

Comment: `Last Logged` has a space in it. You need to either change it so it does not or wrap it in backticks. Also, this would be simpler if you just let MySQL set the date for you by using CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: this code is **vulnerable to sql injection** please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php